# Broken search after moving folders

Tags: php, joomla, navigation

I am working on a Joomla site and have moved it from its root /public_html folder to a new folder called /portfolio.

Doing this resulted in the search function breaking on the site in the top right of the site.  I can't seem to figure out how to solve this issue.

Here is the code for the search box which was working before I moved this site to the subdirectory of /portfolio.

```
<form action="/portfolio/results" method="get">
      <div class="search_div">
        <span class="search_div_padding">
            Search the material: <input type="text" name="stone" value="<?php if ($_GET['stone']) echo urldecode($_GET['stone']);?>" class="input_search" />
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="button_search_submit" />
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!  Here is the site in question:

http://abcworldwidestone.com/portfolio/

Thanks!

Comment: did you change the name of directory material-portfolio to portfolio ?

Comment: The Main Navigation is called "material-portfolio" then there is the subnavigation so it should be /portfolio/material-portfolio/marble as an example for the marble page.

*EDIT* I went ahead and changed "material-portfolio" to "portfolio"

Comment: All links of the left menu has /portfolio string twice so you may have stored that somewhere in your component and has to be removed. Please try also **menu -> rebuild** and clear joomla and browser cache.

Comment: Weird because I  haven't touched the component, all I did was place this site in the /portfolio folder and the whole thing messed up.  I also don't have a Menu Rebuild because this site is running on Joomla 1.5.  Any other suggestions?  I also noticed that when you click on a menu link, that 404 error page is from the Wordpress site (that's located on the root folder) and not the Joomla site itself.